# "Got 1 columns instead of ..." error in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm working on the following code for performing Random Forest Classification on train and test sets;

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

def main():
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('filepath','r'), delimiter=' ', dtype='f8')   
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('filepath','r'), delimiter=' ', dtype='f8')

    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    rf.fit(train, target)
    predicted_probs = [[index + 1, x[1]] for index, x in enumerate(rf.predict_proba(test))]

    savetxt('filepath', predicted_probs, delimiter=',', fmt='%d,%f', 
            header='Id,PredictedProbability', comments = '')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

However I get the following error on execution;

```
---->      dataset = genfromtxt(open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/pgm/Cora/a_train.csv','r'), delimiter='', dtype='f8')

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #88 (got 1435 columns instead of 1434)
    Line #93 (got 1435 columns instead of 1434)
    Line #164 (got 1435 columns instead of 1434)
    Line #169 (got 1435 columns instead of 1434)
    Line #524 (got 1435 columns instead of 1434)
...
...
...
```

Any suggestions as to how avoid it?? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

`genfromtxt` will give this error if the number of columns is unequal.

I can think of 3 ways around it:

**1. Use the [`usecols`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) parameter**

```
np.genfromtxt('yourfile.txt',delimiter=',',usecols=np.arange(0,1434))
```

However - this may mean that you lose some data (where rows are longer than 1434 columns) - whether or not that matters is down to you.

**2. Adjust your input data file so that it has an equal number of columns.**

**3. Use something other than `genfromtxt:`**

.............[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974290/reading-non-uniform-data-from-file-into-array-with-numpy)

Answer (score 6):

An exception is raised if an inconsistency is detected in the number of columns.A number of reasons and solutions are possible.

1. Add `invalid_raise = False` to skip the offending lines.

   `dataset = genfromtxt(open('data.csv','r'), delimiter='', invalid_raise = False)`
2. If your data contains Names, make sure that the field name doesn’t contain any space or invalid character, or that it does not correspond to the name of a standard attribute (like size or shape), which would confuse the interpreter.

> 1. `deletechars`
>
>    Gives a string combining all the characters that must be deleted from the name. By default, invalid characters are
>      `~!@#$%^&*()-=+~\|]}[{';: /?.>,<.`
> 2. `excludelist`
>
>    Gives a list of the names to exclude, such as `return, file, print…` If one of the input name is part of this list, an underscore
>      character ('_') will be appended to it.
> 3. `case_sensitive`
>
>    Whether the names should be case-sensitive (`case_sensitive=True`), converted to upper case
>      (`case_sensitive=False` or `case_sensitive='upper'`) or to lower case
>      (`case_sensitive='lower'`).

```
data = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", dtype=None, names=True,\
       deletechars="~!@#$%^&*()-=+~\|]}[{';: /?.>,<.", case_sensitive=True)
```

Reference: [numpy.genfromtxt](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html)

Answer (score 4):

You have too many columns in one of your rows. For example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> s = """
... 1 2 3 4
... 1 2 3 4 5
... """
>>> np.genfromtxt(StringIO(s),delimiter=" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1654, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 5 columns instead of 4)
```

Comment: can we get this done if number of columns are not equal?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error aroused due to having a **special symbol** in the row.

Error cause: having special characters like

- '#' hash
- ',' given the fact that your ( delimiter = ',' )

Example csv file

- 1,hello,**#this**,fails
- 1,hello,**',this'**,fails

  ## -----CODE-----

  import numpy as numpy
  data = numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=delimeter) #Error

Environment Note:

**OS**: Ubuntu

**csv editor**: LibreOffice

**IDE**: Pycharm

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers worked for me so for future googlers here is another one :

Error was  : `"Line #88 (got 1435 columns instead of 1)"`

Discovered that my csv file was a utf8 encoded text file with a BOM(a character marking the encoding on the first line of the file. Most text editors will hide this character)

I simply opened it in notepad in windows,"saved as" again and selected "ANSI" at the bottom of the save box.

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. The cause was a single entry in my data that had a space. This caused it to see it as an extra row. Make sure all spacing is consistent throughout all the data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the header that includes the column names have 1 more column than the data itself (1435 columns on header vs. 1434 on data).

You could either:

1) Eliminate 1 column from the header that doesn't make sense with data

OR

2) Use the skip header from genfromtxt()
for example, `np.genfromtxt('myfile', skip_header=*how many lines to skip*, delimiter=' ')` 
more information found in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#the-skip-header-and-skip-footer-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error when I was also trying to load a text dataset with genfromtext and do text classification with Keras.

The data format was: `[some_text]\t[class_label]`.
My understanding was that there are some characters in the 1st column that somehow confuse the parser and the two columns cannot be split properly.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(my_file.csv, delimiter='\t', usecols=(0,1), dtype=str);
```

this snippet created the same ValueError with yours and my first workaround was to read everything as one column:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(my_file, delimiter='\t', usecols=(0), dtype=str);
```

and split the data later by myself.

However, what finally worked properly was to explicitly define the comment parameter in genfromtxt.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(my_file, delimiter='\t', usecols=(0,1), dtype=str, comments=None);
```

According to the documentation:

> The optional argument comments is used to define a character string
>   that marks the beginning of a comment. By default, genfromtxt assumes
>   comments='#'. The comment marker may occur anywhere on the line. **Any
>   character present after the comment marker(s) is simply ignored**.

the default character that indicates a comment is '#', and thus if this character is included in your text column, everything is ignored after it. That is probably why the two columns cannot be recognized by genfromtext.