# Numpy ValueError (got 1 columns instead of 2)

Tags: python, numpy

Before someone points out duplicate, this is not the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353585/got-1-columns-instead-of-error-in-numpy).

In that question, his error was

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #88 (got 1435 columns instead of 1434)
```

having 1 more column than expected (likely an extra delimiter somewhere).

I am processing a file with two columns separated by a tab ('\t') and am using the following

```
movies = np.genfromtxt('imdb/movie_keywords', delimiter = '\t', dtype = None)
```

I receive the following error

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #44209 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
Line #44210 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
Line #44211 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
Line #93460 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
...
```

Here are four lines (raw text) from the file,

The first two are line #1 and line #, which do not throw an errors

```
'$ (1971)\tbank-heist'
'Angela (1954)\tamerican-car-salesman'
```

These are from lines #44209 # 93463, which throw an error

```
'Animated (1989)\taustralian'
'Animated Motion #1 (1976)\tindependent-film'
```

Might some sleuth point out the difference here which causes numpy not to pick up the tab in the error throwing lines?

To add, I receive no error if using pandas and this code:

```
keywords = pd.read_csv('imdb/movie_keywords', delimiter = '\t', dtype = None, names = ['movie', 'keyword'])
```

Pandas however is not sufficient for the operations I wish to conduct.

Comment: You might encounter this error if `Animated (1989)\taustralian` contains a literal backslash followed by a literal `t` instead of a tab character.

Comment: @unutbu the text from the file: "Animated (1989) australian"

Comment: `genfromtxt` reports line numbers with the count starting at 1. Python uses 0-based indexing. Depending on how you located the the 44209th line, there might be an "off-by-one" error. It might not hurt to check the line preceding `'Animated (1989)\taustralian'` too.

Comment: @unutbu Good thinking, I had considered this. This is why I chose line #93463 As lines #93460-#93465 all return errors.

Comment: Could you post the `repr` of these lines?

Comment: @unutbu repr is what was used to produce the raw strings in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of this question was to find the issue with Numpy, as stated in the question using Pandas results in no error. If someone is however looking for a workaround, this seems to work:

```
keywords = pd.read_csv('imdb/movie_keywords', delimiter = '\t', dtype = None, names = ['movie', 'keyword'])

keywords_array = keywords.as_matrix()
```

Comment: Did you try `genfromtxt` with the `names` parameter?