# ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'user1'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am testing and training text dataset but getting this error. CSV file contains texts.

When I run the code, it gives the output:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'user1'`

and here `user1` is a text inside a dataset

**Code:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np


seed = 9
np.random.seed(seed)

dataset = np.loadtxt('E:/7th Semester/FYP/ini/New 
folder/MBAT/DataSet/train_data.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)


X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, 
random_state=seed)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), nb_epoch=100, 
batch_size=5)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print ("Accuracy: %.2f%%" %(scores[1]*100))
```

**Complete Traceback error**:

```
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 725, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'user1'
```

Comment: Hi @dashti, Can you share the full `Traceback` error? This will help identify which part of code is causing the error.

Comment: hi @amanb , 
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 725, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'user1'

Comment: @dashti The **FULL** backtrace, and please in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: i just added traceback in question. @MatthieuBrucher

Comment: Doesn't a complete Traceback always start with `Traceback`?

Comment: Without a sample of the `csv` text file we can't help.  The discussion indicates that this file not only has string columns, but has variable length rows, or missing values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation for [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), the `dtype` for the resulting array from `numpy.loadtxt()` is `float`. Now, `user1` is a string and cannot be converted to `float`, and therefore you are getting this error. You could try the following:

```
np.genfromtxt('/path/to/csv', dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True, case_sensitive=True, invalid_raise=False)
```

Comment: I just added another approach using `np.genfromtxt()`. You could try that.

Comment: got this error when tried np.genformtxt()

ValueError: Some errors were detected !

    Line #5 (got 5 columns instead of 4)

    Line #8 (got 2 columns instead of 4)

    Line #11 (got 6 columns instead of 4)

Comment: If your csv has mixed dtypes, you should use `dtype=None`, I've edited the answer. Also, the error you are getting is due to the inconsistency detected in the number of columns. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353585/got-1-columns-instead-of-error-in-numpy) suggests a workaround which I'm adding to my answer.

Comment: Please refer to suggested answer to resolve column inconsistencies. I've added the argument `invalid_raise=False` to my answer. However, unless we are not sure what type of data exists in the csv, we cannot suggest what may work for you.

Comment: i have int and string data in csv file

Comment: Y = dataset[:,8] from this line code got this error now.  IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Comment: This most likely means there are 4 columns, but you have specified index 8 which is out of bounds. Change that to 4.